# class name convention in react material-ui framework

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a class name convention used in material ui library? I'm currently using [material-ui-next](https://material-ui-next.com/). I notice class names like "MuiFormControl-root-124" all over the place with numbers appended to class name. For Paper element "MuiPaper-root-18 MuiPaper-shadow2-22 MuiPaper-rounded-19". I just can't see a pattern here.

Is there a convention which I'm missing. It would be easier to understand this framework if it made sense like Bootstraps grid classes. All help much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In material-ui v1, class names are non-deterministically generated at run time, so there is no convention you should adhere to. That's described [here](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/#class-names) in the docs:

> You may have noticed that the class names generated by our styling solution are non-deterministic, so you can't rely on them to stay the same.

However, that does not matter because you should never be using raw CSS class names in the first place. Instead, you use [`withStyles`](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component) to set the appropriate styles for each component:

```
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

// Define the CSS styles you which to apply to your component
const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    // withStyles automatically provides the classes prop, which
    // will contain the generated CSS class name that you can match
    // to your component
    return <div className={this.props.classes.root} />;
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

These non-deterministic class names have technical benefits, including improved performance:

> Thanks to the non-deterministic nature of our class names, we can implement optimizations for development and production. They are easy to debug in development and as short as possible in production.

You should note that this happens because material-ui takes a fundamentally different approach to styling than a library like Bootstrap. While Bootstrap has a CSS library with defined class names that get applied to each element, material-ui uses [CSS in JS](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/#material-ui-39-s-styling-solution) to inject styling. This allows CSS to be defined and stored alongside the JavaScript definition of each component.