# Are default or pre-built classes provided in material UI?

Tags: material-ui

Does material UI provide pre-built class names like bootstrap does. For example: `.pull-right, .pull-left`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [class name convention in react material-ui framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161450/class-name-convention-in-react-material-ui-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI has it's own styling solution, among that one can override it's default `css` class names.

Take a look [here](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/overrides/).